# jQuery is moving div when setting height of another div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have tried to introduce myself into tableless layouts using divs. A first try was the inner content of this (german) page:

http://bit.ly/RnSdGP (Shorturl, because it is a test site not intended to show up in search engines)

Generally, this works perfectly! But now I wanted to set the height of the list on the height dynamically. I found out, that this only works using jQuery. My first approach was the following snippet:

```
$(window).load(function() {     
        $(".scrollBox").height($(".gameInfo").height());    
    });
```

In general, the snippet does what it says. But it does even more! It moves the part (div with class "texts") with the windows icons and the text below the whole box. Why? Without the script, the layout is fine, but the point that the scrollbox is not being resized to the right content :)

I can set the height to 2000 in the script, but the result is that the texts-field is moved down below the whole box.

Maybe someone can see what I'm doing wrong, thanks in advance :)

Greets

Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set in css

```
vertical-align: top;
```

for both containers. Could fix it

PS: Dein halber Beitrag ist in Englisch, der andere in Deutsch

Comment: Which containers do you mean? scrollBox and texts? If so, this does not fix the problem.

PS: Oh, da scheint mir was beim Übersetzen entgangen zu sein :) Danke!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the div ".innerGameInfo .texts" has clear:both applied to it, and the column that you're resizing (.scrollbox) is floated, so when you resize it, the .texts element will appear below it (due to the clear:both).  I would suggest removing clear:both from .texts, and setting a height on the div above it (or use clearfix) to prevent .texts from overlapping it.

Comment: Well, If I remove the clear: both, the texts field will appear directly below the cover and overlaps the ratings (the green box below the game cover). What is this clearfix exactly? Read about that, but never get to know how to use ;)

Comment: It's a stylesheet and class that you can apply to an element that has floating children to ensure across browsers that the containing element resizes to fit it's content.  Without it, in some browsers, the containing element will not increase in size to the size of it's contents - see http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Comment: Well, just have done that. Well better result, but now the "cover" div is overlapping the "texts" div. How to solve this?